# Find contour integral around the circle $\oint\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> $$\oint\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)}dz$$ counterclockwise around the circle $|z|=2$

I have substituted $z=2e^{it}$, $dz=2e^{it}dt$...

My integral is now:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{4e^{it}-1}{4e^{2it}-2e^{it}}$$
Can anyone advice with the next step to take?

Comment: Or use Cauchy's integral formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no need of the substitution. Note that the integrand isn't analytic at the points $z =0, 1$ both of which lie inside $C$. Writing it as, $$\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)} = (1-2z)\left[\frac1{z}-\frac1{z-1}\right]$$ and using the Cauchy's integral formula gives us: $$I =2\pi i \left[(1-2(0))-(1-2(1))\right] =4\pi i$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)}\,dz = \int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-1}\,dz+\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-0}\,dz.$$
and, since both $1$ and $0$ are in $|z|<2$, by using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) with $f(z)=1$, it follows that
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)}\,dz=2\pi i\cdot 1+2\pi i\cdot 1=4\pi i.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)} =\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z}.$$
then, by cauchy integral formula

$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)}\,dz = \int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-1}\,dz+\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z}\,dz =4πi.$$